# How to get SCI impact factor from other than Journal site

Tags: science, impact-factor, social-science

I could see the IF of journal I am looking for in their site. My problem is Thomsor Reuters report lists the journal as indexed in both SCI and SSCI, but kournal home page says its indexed in SSCI only. And it lists impact factor too. How can I confirm whether its really indexed in SCI and find its IF? I couldnt get a proper reply after contacting Journal. Can I get it anywhere in Thomson Reuters site?

Answer (score 1):

To see if the journal is indexed in SCI or SSCI, you can search from Clarivate's [master journal list](http://mjl.clarivate.com/#journal_lists). Checking the Impact Factor probably require subscription to Web of Science. Alternatively you can directly search for the journal titles in [BioXBio](https://www.bioxbio.com/) or find any article for the journal to see Impact Factor in [Scinapse](https://scinapse.io/).

(edit: I work with Pluto Network developing and servicing Scinapse.)